# Generic host builder

Tags: c#, .net-core

What would be the equivalent code of web host builder for generic host builder for console application in 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting':

```
var hostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseConfiguration(config).UseStartup<TStartup>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find exactly analog. I use the next code for that. For my background services.

```cs
 public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {


            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost => configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables("ASPNETCORE_"))
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                {
                    configApp.SetBasePath(GetConfigDirectoryPath());
                    configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
                    configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
                })
                .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
                .UseHostedService<MyBackgroundService>()
                .Build();

            await host.RunAsync();
        }


  private static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext hostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(hostBuilderContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

            services.AddTransient<IDbContextProvider<AppDbContext>, DefaultDbContextProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWorkManager, UnitOfWorkManager>();

            services.AddTransient(typeof(IUnitOfWork), typeof(EfCoreUnitOfWork));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<>), typeof(EfCoreReadOnlyRepositoryBase<>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<,>), typeof(EfCoreReadOnlyRepositoryBase<,>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EfCoreRepositoryBase<>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(EfCoreRepositoryBase<,>));

            services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options => options.Configuration = hostBuilderContext.Configuration.GetSection("Redis:Configuration").Value);

            //Register AutoMapper profiles
            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
            services.AddAutoMapper(assemblies);
        }
```

Is implementing background service

```
  public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
```

```cs
  public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IHostBuilder UseHostedService<T>(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
            where T : class, IHostedService, IDisposable
        {
            return hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                services.AddHostedService<T>());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would have been nice if you could elaborate what exactly you are looking for but following is from my sample console application written in .net6. wrote this to show-case dependency injection and use of `NLog` with `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`

[Skip following and Get the source from Github](https://github.com/gandalf7777/Netfx6DependencyInjectionLoggingExample/tree/main/DependencyInjectionLoggingExample)

**Program.cs**

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using RedBeans.Examples.Console.DependencyInjectionLoggingExample;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<MyApplication>()
        .AddTransient<AnotherClass>()
        .AddOptions<ConfigSection1Settings>().Bind(context.Configuration.GetSection("ConfigSection1"));
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddConfiguration(context.Configuration.GetSection("NLog"));
        logging.AddNLog();
    })
    .RunConsoleAsync();
```

**MyApplication.cs**

```
namespace RedBeans.Examples.Console.DependencyInjectionLoggingExample;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
internal class MyApplication : IHostedService
{
    private int? _exitCode;
    private readonly ILogger<MyApplication> _logger;
    private readonly AnotherClass _another;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _applicationLifetime;

    public MyApplication(IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, AnotherClass another, ILogger<MyApplication> logger)
    {
        _applicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
        _another = another;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Starting Application with arguments: {string.Join(";", Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())}");
        _applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("My Application Business logic starts here!!!");
                    _another.AnotherFunction();
                    await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
                    _exitCode = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception");
                    _exitCode = 1;
                }
                finally
                {
                    _applicationLifetime.StopApplication();
                }
            });
        });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug($"Exiting with return code: {_exitCode}");
        Environment.ExitCode = _exitCode.GetValueOrDefault(-1);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**AnotherClass.cs**

```
namespace RedBeans.Examples.Console.DependencyInjectionLoggingExample;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

internal class AnotherClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IOptions<ConfigSection1Settings> _configSection1;
    public AnotherClass(IOptions<ConfigSection1Settings> configSection1, ILogger<AnotherClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configSection1 = configSection1;
    }
    public void AnotherFunction()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"I can tell you the value of configSection1.Config1 is {_configSection1.Value.Config1}");
    }
}
```

**ConfigSection1Settings.cs**

```
namespace RedBeans.Examples.Console.DependencyInjectionLoggingExample;
internal sealed class ConfigSection1Settings
{
    public string? Config1 { get; set; }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConfigSection1": {
    "Config1": "Value1"
  },
  "NLog": {
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "targets": {
      "async": true,
      "logfile": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "c:/temp/nlog-${shortdate}.log"
      },
      "logconsole": {
        "type": "Console"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "Microsoft.*",
        "maxLevel": "Error",
        "final": true
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "logconsole"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Debug",
        "writeTo": "logfile"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Project File**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT: Your config class can be internal, but your properties MUST be public.